# how to solve this err in hardhat vs code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, blockchain, hardhat

> You are using a version of Node.js that is not supported by Hardhat,
> and it may work incorrectly, or not work at all. Please, make sure you
> are using a supported version of Node.js. To learn more about which
> versions of Node.js are supported go to
> https://hardhat.org/nodejs-versions
>
> An unexpected error occurred:
>
> ```
> Error: Cannot find module '@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle'
> Require stack:
> - D:\3.1\dppa\hardhat.config.js
> - D:\3.1\dppa\node_modules\hardhat\internal\core\config\config-loading.js
> - D:\3.1\dppa\node_modules\hardhat\internal\cli\cli.js
>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:939:15)
>     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:780:27)
>     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
>     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\3.1\dppa\hardhat.config.js:1:1)
>     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
>     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
>     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
>   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
>   requireStack: [
>     'D:\\3.1\\dppa\\hardhat.config.js',
>     'D:\\3.1\\dppa\\node_modules\\hardhat\\internal\\core\\config\\config-loading.js',
>     'D:\\3.1\\dppa\\node_modules\\hardhat\\internal\\cli\\cli.js'
>   ]
> }
> PS D:\3.1\dppa>
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to run the sample project and are missing plugins.

As stated [here](https://hardhat.org/guides/project-setup#plugins-and-dependencies), you need to install some plugins for the sample project with the following command.

```
npm install --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle ethereum-waffle chai @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers ethers
```

Besides that, as stated in the [provided link](https://hardhat.org/reference/stability-guarantees#node.js-versions-support),  you should use the latest `LTS` of `Node.js`, which is `Node.js 16` and can be downloaded [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)